# Cron is retrying a job every 15 minutes

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron

I have an Amazon Linux AMI with this in crontab:

```
0 7 * * 1 root /usr/bin/wget -q http://localhost/digest_weekly.php -O - >> /var/log/digest_weekly.log
```

This calls the script `digest_weekly.php` every Monday at 7am. This script collects some data from the database and sends an email to each user. It returns a list of all the email addresses to which it sent an email. Today it had to send 2608 emails. The script takes a while to execute, but I can't see timeout errors in my logs.

The problem is that the mails are sent again every 15 minutes. `/var/log/digest_weekly.log` is empty, so I guess that the job didn't finish and somehow cron is launching it again after giving it some time. I see this in the Apache access logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2016:07:00:01 +0000] "GET /digest_weekly.php HTTP/1.1" 200 70941 "-" "Wget/1.16.1 (linux-gnu)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2016:07:15:02 +0000] "GET /digest_weekly.php HTTP/1.1" 200 70941 "-" "Wget/1.16.1 (linux-gnu)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2016:07:30:04 +0000] "GET /digest_weekly.php HTTP/1.1" 200 70917 "-" "Wget/1.16.1 (linux-gnu)"
```

But in `/var/log/cron` I can see only one line:

```
May 30 07:00:01 ip-172-31-8-62 CROND[8104]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/wget -q http://localhost/digest_weekly.php -O - >> /var/log/synkratos/digest_weekly.log)
```

Other cron jobs are executed just fine (hourly, daily).

Why is this cron job repeated? Last week it was executed 4 times, today 9 (until I killed the task).

Comment: `-q` (quiet) argument to populate log file will never work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a cron issue, rather [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options) restarting the download after reaching the  default timeout of 900 seconds:

> **`--read-timeout=seconds`** 
>              Set the read (and write) timeout to seconds seconds.  The "time" of this timeout refers to idle time: if, at any point in the download, no data is
>              received for more than the specified number of seconds, reading fails and the download is restarted.  This option does not directly affect the
>              duration of the entire download.
>   Of course, the remote server may choose to terminate the connection sooner than this option requires.  The **default read timeout is `900`** seconds.

Rather than executing your PHP script by calling a web server you should probably run the script from the commandline PHP interpreter, i.e. something along the lines of:

```
0 7 * * 1 root /usr/bin/php /path/to/digest_weekly.php  >> /var/log/digest_weekly.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is really cron (at least that line) who sends the requests? The fastest way to check: comment out that line and check cron logs later.

Perhaps there's another schedule.